# Qt.createComponent() causes later "Object already has a QQmlContext" error when binding dynamically

Tags: qt, qml, qt6

I'm getting this error with pure QML (no C++):

```
QQmlEngine::setContextForObject(): Object already has a QQmlContext
```

It happens when a binding is created dynamically, but **only if** some component was previously loaded at run-time using `Qt.createComponent(url)`.

What is strange is that the error occurs regardless of what component was loaded dynamically or whether that component is ever used for anything.  The mere fact of dynamically loading a component seems set up conditions for this error to occur later.

Here is a demo.  Run with `qml main.qml` :

```
// main.qml
import QtQuick

Rectangle {
  id: top; visible:true; width:300; height:300;

  MyType { }

  Component.onCompleted: {
    // Load a do-nothing component at run-time, and never use it
    let url = Qt.resolvedUrl(".")+"/Unrelated.qml"; // linux
    let comp = Qt.createComponent(url);
    if (comp.status == Component.Ready) {
      print(`comp is Ready`);
    } else {
      console.log("Not Ready: "+ comp.errorString());
    }
  }
}
```

```
// MyType.qml
import QtQuick 2.14

Item {
  property double bid
  Other { id:other }
    
  Component.onCompleted: {
    print(`MyType onCompleted: About to create binding...`);
    bid = Qt.binding(function() { return other.bid });
    print(`MyType onCompleted: binding created.`);
    print(`MyType onCompleted: value is ${bid}`);
  }
}
```

```
// Other.qml
import QtQuick 2.14
QtObject {
  property double bid: 42
}
```

```
// Unrelated.qml
import QtQuick 2.14
Item { }
```

Comment: remove version in MyType.qml, Other.qml and Unrelated.qml

Comment: I see.  Leaving off the version causes errors if using Qt 5.x

The problem seems to be not using the same QtQuick version everywhere.  Leaving the version off in main.qml is inconsistent with specifying 2.14 elsewhere.  BTW if I use 2.15 everywhere it works with both Qt5 & Qt6.

Comment: In your first code (main.qml) you are not using versions because I assume you are using Qt6 and the other versions are just remnants of Qt5.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Our comments crossed